# How to block google from indexing mail record. duplication issue mail.example.com which is duplication of example.com

Tags: google, web-crawlers

google is causing duplication by indexing mail.example.com which is identical to home page of [www.example.com/](http://www.example.com/)

I  added property in search console and removed this subdomain but keeps on indexing every now and then, I'm trying to add robots.txt in mail folder to block it any good?

Comment: Why have you configured your HTTP server to serve the same content for www and mail in the first place?

Comment: I didn't perform any configuration on HTTP server, it is configured by the hosting company.